# Pdf Join Cat wrong

Tags: php, pdf

```
shell_exec('pdftk offerletter/'.$_GET['id'].'.pdf LAMPIRAN_A.pdf cat output offerletter2/'.$_GET['id'].'.pdf dont_ask');

header('location:offerletter2/'.$_GET['id'].'.pdf');
```

situation :
example : $_GET['id']=123456789;

student will download offerletter name 123456789, which it will save under folder offerletter. And in offerletter folder, have LAMPIRAN_A.pdf that will join with the student offerletter, and 
after join, it will output to another folder, which name offerletter2

error :
cannot find offerletter2/123456789.pdf

Comment: Can you confirm that the offerletter2/123456789.pdf file really exists? If it does not then you may not have permission to run pdftk.

Comment: offerletter2/123456789.pdf will be generate after cat with LAMPIRAN_A

Comment: Can you confirm that the file does really exist now? What is the output of pdftk? I am assuming it takes two files, and generate a third one ("output"?) or sends the output to stdout. The text you posted seems to be incrorrect or pdftk understands the 'cat' argument. In case pdftk generates output then you may want to change cat to cp.

Comment: yaa.. i have 123456789.pdf in folder offerletter, and i want to join with LAMPIRAN_A.pdf, and make a new pdf after i join 123456789.pdf and LAMPIRAN_A.pdf to offerletter2,

Comment: Example : folder A :- q.pdf(have 1 slide). LAMPIRAN_A.pdf(have 2 slide). Join q.pdf and LAMPIRAN_A.pdf, so it will have 3 slide. save output at folder b which have same name like the 1st pdf. folder b:-g.pdf(have 3 slide)

Comment: I have found manual on the website, and your command like is correct. Then the very last question thing you need to do is to confirm that you are NOT having the output generated. Then run the same command on the server from the command line, and confirm that it works. If this is the case then your server has no permission to run pdftk. You will need to write a script (pdftk.sh) that does the same as you do now, and you need to change its ownership to the root, and do chmod +s pdftk.sh (now I am not sure if I remember this well) to allow this script running other executables.